# What is the best workflow for dealing with modifiers and complex objects?

Tags: modifiers, workflow

I'm coming from Cinema 4D and a new user. I'm trying to figure out the Blender version of this kind of workflow:

1. Download car (for example) model from Turbosquid (made of hundreds of objects in a complex hierarchy)
2. Apply subdivision (or bevel) to the entire hierarchy non-destructively (in C4D this would be putting the entire Car hierarchy under a Subdivision Surface.
3. Apply effects to the entire hierarchy: For example, 'bending' the entire car using a single bend deformer.

I initially tried to use modifiers in Blender like this, but I'm confused by how they seem to only affect single objects and don't flow through the object hierarchy. Again I'm new to Blender so I'm probably missing something basic.

Comment: Yeah, in Blender you often need to select multiple objects (shift+G) or the different (shift+L) and apply effects to all of them via Ctrl+L or right-clicking a value and selecting 'Copy to Selected'

Comment: Your question is really broad but for your particular case, you need to tweak the modifiers in one of your objects, then select all of them and lastly the object with the modifiers, and link them with CTRL + L > Modifiers. In order to bend all objects at once you need to use the lattice modifier and a lattice object, then copy your modifier to all the others. Notice that *some* fields in the modifiers can be edited on multiple objects by pressing ALT + click on the field and changing the value

Comment: Thanks this is helpful. I'll explore these methods.

Answer (score 1):

For bending an object (yeah, it's simpler if you combine all into one), you can use Mesh Deform modifier.

1. Make the cage around the car, simple box with subdivisions. Make it wire viewport visibility
2. Add the Mesh Deform modifier to the car and select the box and bind
3. Put Simple Deform modifier to the Cage object, or some other modifier

[image]